# How to print an OBB(array of float3) in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to print an OBB for the Game Engine I'm doing for a College Subject: https://github.com/VictorSegura99/Alien-GameEngine.

I get the array of float3 with MathGeoLib using the OBB struct that gets the data from a currently loaded FBX, but it could be any set of points to print with OpenGL.

The OBB works correctly because I use it to make a global AABB and I print the AABB with direct mode and it works pretty well.
The problem is that I can't print the OBB with direct mode, so I have to use the set of points.

The actual code I'm using is this

```
    glColor3f(OBB_color.r, OBB_color.g, OBB_color.b);
    float3* obb_points=nullptr;
    obb.GetCornerPoints(obb_points);

    glGenBuffers(1, &obb_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obb_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(obb_points)*3, obb_points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeof(obb_points) * 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I expect OpenGL to print the OBB connecting the outside points with lines.

Comment: The last parameter of `glDrawArrays` has to be the number of vertices rather than number of "floats" in the buffer, neither the size of the buffer in bytes. Further note, since the type of `obb_points` is  `float3*`, is `sizeof(obb_points)` the size of the pointer (8 at a 64bit system). It doesn't magically return the number of elements in the dynamically allocated buffer.  That's basic c++!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution yesterday.

I found the function `CornerPoint(int index)` in the OBB struct, so I connected the points with direct mode.